# Population of last row value based on match condition in R

Tags: r, match

I have following input data.

```
               Time Flag    Spread
2016-06-01 09:30:01 new     0
2016-06-01 09:30:04 matched 0.04
2016-06-01 09:30:05 new     0
2016-06-01 09:30:06 new     0
2016-06-01 09:31:02 matched 0.05
2016-06-01 09:31:08 matched 0.04
2016-06-01 09:32:03 matched 0.05
2016-06-01 09:33:09 matched 0.01
2016-06-01 09:34:01 new     0
2016-06-01 09:35:03 matched 0.12
2016-06-01 09:35:04 new     0
2016-06-01 09:35:06 matched 0.08
2016-06-01 09:35:09 matched 0.05
```

I am looking for below output from above input.

```
               Time Flag    Spread
2016-06-01 09:30:01 new     0
2016-06-01 09:30:04 matched 0.04
2016-06-01 09:30:05 new     0.04
2016-06-01 09:30:06 new     0.04
2016-06-01 09:31:02 matched 0.05
2016-06-01 09:31:08 matched 0.04
2016-06-01 09:32:03 matched 0.05
2016-06-01 09:33:09 matched 0.01
2016-06-01 09:34:01 new     0.01
2016-06-01 09:35:03 matched 0.12
2016-06-01 09:35:04 new     0.12
2016-06-01 09:35:06 matched 0.08
2016-06-01 09:35:09 matched 0.05
```

Algo: Rows with `Flag == "new"` will be populating value of `Spread` column from last `Flag == "match"` row. Last `match` means it is from time-sorted list.

```
Algo Update: If first row/first few rows of data is Flag == "new",
then Spread of those rows will remain 0.
```

Can you please suggest simple `R` implementation for the same.

```
Update: Updated first row of input and output data as well as Algo,
to reflect updated query based on primary reply from @Gregor.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
your_data$Spread = zoo::na.locf(ifelse(
    your_data$Flag == "new", NA, your_data$Spread
))
```

This is a straightforward application of "last observation carried forward". I assume your data is already sorted in the order you want.

Comment: just to update my original query: sometimes if first row of data having Flag == "new". Then for that row I want Spread = 0 to remain same. Can you suggest extension to your original code?

Comment: Set `na.rm = FALSE` in `zoo::na.locf` and then followup with `your_data$Spread[is.na(your_data$Spread)] = 0`.

Comment: Or replace the `zoo::na.locf` with `zoo::na.fill(<ifelse from answer>, fill = list(0, "extend", "extend"))`.